# Dagger 2 Create subcomponent with a component with no module bindings

Tags: java, dagger-2, dagger

I have some subcomponents that I’m updating to use Builders.

I’m declaring the subcomponents on their respective parents’ modules. I have one module that doesn’t have any bindings itself, so it only exists to let me inject my subcomponent builder.

```
@MySubcomponentScope @Subcomponent(modules = MySubcomponent.Module.class) interface MySubcomponent {
  @dagger.Module(subcomponents = DeeperSubcomponent.class) abstract class Module { } // All the bindings are in MySubcomponent.Builder.
}
```

Is there a way to get around this empty module class?

A complete and tiny working example to demonstrate exactly my question: https://gist.github.com/NightlyNexus/82c8138816c6b4db9afd7785f3396f47